# how to trigger an URL to invoke a proxy services in wso2esb

Tags: url, uri, endpoint, wso2-esb

I want to invoke the proxy services using an url. That is If I gave the url a user can use that as an endpoint for them to push data. So how can I invoke the proxy service when i trigger the url. I went for custom url but it was not valid. I am using WSO2ESB management console. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got it right. But if you created a http proxy like this, you can go to the management console, click on the proxy name and there you'll see the URL of the proxy.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="HTTPProxy"
       transports="http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">....
```

http://servername:8280/services/HTTPProxy

Comment: Thanks Martin its correct. http://servername:8280/services/Proxy (if we try in SOAP UI and pass parameters we need). Proxy- Proxy service Name